# in c# code why below copy didn't work as reference copy?

Tags: c#, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Below c# code I run in Visual Studio 2019 Mac, I am a little surprise for the result:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public int x;
        private int y;
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
            Point p2;
            p2 = p1;
            p1.x = 200;
            Console.WriteLine("p1.x is {0},p2.x is {1} ", p1.x, p2.x);
            // I think here should Output: p1.x is 200, p2.x is 200
            // But the actual output is: p1.x is 200, p2.x is 100, why? is it a reference copy?
            // p1 and p2 should share the same reference, right?
        }

    }
}
```

Actually when I read C# instruction, it explained that such code should output:
p1.x is 200,p2.x is 200
because p2 and p1 share the same pointer to point to ONE address in heap, right? while when I try to test above code in VS2019 Mac. it's output is:
p1.x is 200,p2.x is 100
which confused me so much?
Is it a shallow copy or deep copy?
Can somebody please explain why p2.x is still 100, when p1.x already changed to 200?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Point` is a `struct`.  When you assigned `p2` to `p1`, `p2` became a copy.  I think you might want to read up a bit more on [value types versus reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Structs are value types in C# which means that they will assign by value. That means that when you assign `p1` to `p2`, it is copying the values instead of the memory location. If you want this to have the behavior that you are looking for, make your point struct a class. Classes are reference types.